# Can I search the People Hub for a part of a phone number?

Tags: search, people-hub

If I use the search option in **People** it seems to search on both company name and surname but not phone numbers.

Is there a way to search for a phone number or part of a phone number in **People**?

Comment: I don't think so. I've tried but didn't work. When I need to find someone by number I make a call and end before the call completes. So I can see in last calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently supported by the native People Hub application. The data is exposed to application developers, so there *might* be a third party app for doing this, although I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 3):

There is a third party app doing just that. It's called truedialer and is available to download for free at the marketplace:
http://www.windowsphone.com/sv-se/apps/8f10c0bf-541b-47f5-a07e-1bffc785e7c1

I just tried it by writing my brothers 5 last numbers and it showed it right away. Clean and simple :)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use the search in your Outlook (online version). Just go to the people hub and search the number.